# Is it possible to install multiple packages at a time or parallely instead of installing one by one in python?

Tags: python, installation

I want to install the numpy and scikit packages at the same moment. But I happened to install them one after the other as below.
[Packageinstallationprocess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9f8R.png)

Is it possible to install them parallel at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do `pip install scipi numpy django pillow example example example`

If you separate them by a space, it will go through and install each package you specified.

Comment: Perfect. I am guessing one can also save a batch file and install multiple packages in one go.

Comment: Is it possible to run pip install in 2 different terminals, in case one library has to be built and takes a long time? (f.g `opencv` with a non-upgraded pip, may take some hours). Or does pip have a similar lock to `apt`/`yum`/etc?

Answer (score 1):

1. create a file with name requirements.txt in a directory.
2. enter packages like this in it:

   matplotlib==1.3.1
   numpy==1.18.4
3. cd to the directory where requirements.txt is located.
4. activate your virtualenv.
5. run: pip install -r requirements.txt in your shell.
   each time you update this file you can install them from file with command in step 5 and do not repeat entering them in shell.